# Weird appearance of themes in Emacs

Tags: emacs, themes, org-mode

I started experiencing this problems, whereby my themes (any of them) don't show properly, but they get mixed in colors, the white spaces sometimes get highlighted, etc. See example below:

[image: Example of the problem]

Has anybody stumbled upon this issue? I upgraded to Emacs 27, and updated my Prelude but it continues like this.

Comment: Looks more like `org-mode` settings that you're not expecting, rather than theming issues. The title and author fields probably have a recommended length, and the break in color shows when you've exceeded that length. Also, it appears that specifically _trailing whitespace_ is highlighted. That's a function of several packages, but I'd bet that `org-mode` has it's own setting.

Comment: it was actually (global-whitespace-mode) that had to be set no nil. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it had to do with white-space mode! Just set

```
(global-whitespace-mode 0)
```

And fixed.

Comment: and that took care of the title and author fields? interesting!

Comment: Yes, all become fixed.